# Can't install python-igraph after installing libigraph0-dev

Tags: python, igraph

I have read a few other posts about installing python-igraph, but I am still unable to finish things off.

I first installed libigraph0-dev, but this only changed the nature of my error and did not fix it. I can't even paste the entire log because it is too many characters, but this is part of log.

First part of the log with some errors

```
Downloading/unpacking python-igraph
  Downloading python-igraph-0.7.1.post6.tar.gz (377kB): 377kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package python-igraph

Installing collected packages: python-igraph
  Running setup.py install for python-igraph
    Build type: dynamic extension
    Include path:
    Library path:
    Runtime library path:
    Linked dynamic libraries: igraph
    Linked static libraries:
    Extra compiler options:
    Extra linker options:
    building 'igraph._igraph' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c src/attributes.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/attributes.o
    In file included from src/attributes.c:24:
    src/attributes.h:27:31: error: igraph_attributes.h: No such file or directory
    src/attributes.h:28:29: error: igraph_datatype.h: No such file or directory
    src/attributes.h:29:30: error: igraph_iterators.h: No such file or directory
    src/attributes.h:30:30: error: igraph_strvector.h: No such file or directory
    src/attributes.h:31:27: error: igraph_vector.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from src/attributes.c:24:
    src/attributes.h:46: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'igraph_t'
    src/attributes.h:46: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
    src/attributes.h:50: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'igraph_t'
    src/attributes.h:50: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
    src/attributes.h:52: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'igraph_t'
    src/attributes.h:52: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
    src/attributes.h:56: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'igraph_t'
    src/attributes.h:56: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
```

End of the log

```
src/attributes.c:1730: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'igraph_t'

src/attributes.c:1730: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token

src/attributes.c:1782: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'igraph_t'

src/attributes.c:1782: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token

src/attributes.c:1817: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'igraphmodule_attribute_table'

src/attributes.c: In function 'igraphmodule_initialize_attribute_handler':

src/attributes.c:1842: warning: implicit declaration of function 'igraph_i_set_attribute_table'

src/attributes.c:1842: error: 'igraphmodule_attribute_table' undeclared (first use in this function)

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/local/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/python-igraph/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-T3WW8S-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/python-igraph
```

Anybody have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the version of `python-igraph` that matches the version number of `libigraph0-dev` and try to compile that. Right now you are downloading `python-igraph` 0.7.1.post6, which should be linked to igraph 0.7.1, but you have an older version of `libigraph0` (and `libigraph0-dev`) on your machine.

If you don't need `libigraph0` for anything else, you can remove `libigraph0` and `libigraph0-dev` and try installing `python-igraph` again from pip. This way `python-igraph` would detect that the C core is not installed, so it would automatically download the right version of the C core and link to it.

Comment: Thanks! I uninstalled both libigraph0 and libigraph0-dev, but pip install python-igraph now ends with the following error.

"/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libxml2.a(entities.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

/usr/lib64/libxml2.a: could not read symbols: Bad value

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Comment: This is a known outstanding issue: https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/16 . A workaround is to temporarily rename `/usr/lib64/libxml2.a` to something else during compilation (so igraph would pick up `/usr/lib64/libxml2.so` instead) and then rename it back.